# Map container is already initialized

Tags: angular, components

I try to achive the coordinate data between components in the angular2,for example:I send the data from sliders.component to map.component through home.component at  the same send the data from map.component to the info.component through home.component. the terminal is ok but the error is occurs on console of the html.

The initmap() in the map.component. I don't know the reason whether the same component don't allow to send and agin the data at the same time or the reason is the wrong code.

**The code of home.component.html as fellow:**

```
<app-maps (notify)="getNotification($event)"></app-maps>
<app-sliders (onDatePicked)="doSomething($event)"></app-sliders>    
<app-maps  [data]="evt"></app-maps>
<app-infos  [data]="spot"></app-infos>
```

**The error is here:**

```
ERROR Error: Map container is already initialized.
    at NewClass._initContainer (leaflet-src.js:3946)
    at NewClass.initialize (leaflet-src.js:3037)
    at new NewClass (leaflet-src.js:300)
    at Object.createMap [as map] (leaflet-src.js:4552)
    at MapsComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/maps/maps.component.ts.MapsComponent.initMap (maps.component.ts:74)
    at MapsComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/maps/maps.component.ts.MapsComponent.ngOnInit (maps.component.ts:90)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10836)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12332)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12271)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13132)
```

Comment: Can you show the code on how you specifically passed the data? You only provided the template.

Comment: from my experience, this error usually causes by other error before this component is hit. "other" error prevented this component to successfully destroyed when you leave. you might have to inspect the console and see if other error before this

Comment: Thank yours! The problem I have solved .the reason is i add the another link to the Map.component.ts.Thanks again!